# How to make Home Assistany History not start on 00:00 the current day

Tags: home-automation

Whenever i check my [Home Assistant](https://home-assistant.io/) History tab in the late evening or early morning I't only shows the few couple of hours that has passed since midnight, even though the period field is set to 1 day.

Is there a way to make it default to showing 24 hours backward in time from now and not cap at the arbitrary time of midnight?

Comment: What is Home Assistant? Can you edit your question to include a link to a homepage or some manuals?

Comment: Any reason why you can't set the period to 2 days?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, selecting 3 day or 1 week does nothing until I also change start date. It's not a huge issue. It just seems it's a quite unreasonable way för HA to cut off the timespan and I'm hoping I'm missing some obvious setting somewhere that fixes it.